# Pass value from ViewModel to platform specific code

Tags: c#, maui

I need to pass custom colour to platform specific `App.xaml` that is located for example in Platforms -> Windows in NET Maui. How I can do that?

In my case I have added following to App.xaml

```
  <maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
    <StaticResource x:Key="NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground" ResourceKey="SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush" Color="Aqua" />
  </maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
```

I want to be able to change this `Color="Aqua"` from my ViewModel. Can somebody give some advice how it can be done?

I have tried following, but it does not seems to be working

```
private void UpdateCustomColorResource(Color color)
{
  var resources = Application.Current.Resources;

  if (resources.ContainsKey("SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush"))
  {
    var accentBrush = (SolidColorBrush)resources["SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush"];

    accentBrush.Color = Colors.Red;
  }
  else
  {
    // Something else
  }
}
```

Comment: Get the resource with that key. Cast it to correct class (SolidColorBrush). Set its Color property.

Comment: You can check this document about the [Application.Resources Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/resource-dictionaries).